# Как удалить select menu и создать сразу же новое, отталкиваясь от выбранного аргумента в 1 select menu?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

Я пытался сделать 2 select menu, чтобы при открытии первого, когда нажимаешь из списка на какой-то аргумент, он удалялся и в зависимости от выбранного аргумента выходил другой select menu. Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать?

```js
    client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

    if (interaction.commandName === 'ping') {
        const row = new MessageActionRow()
            .addComponents(
                new MessageSelectMenu()
                    .setCustomId('select')
                    .setPlaceholder('Nothing selected')
                    .addOptions([
                        {
                            label: 'Select me',
                            description: 'This is a description',
                            value: 'svoya_igra',
                        },
                        {
                            label: 'You can select me too',
                            description: 'This is also a description',
                            value: 'yagadai_malodiu',
                        },
                        {
                            label: 'I am also an option',
                            description: 'This is a description as well',
                            value: 'fortnite',
                        },
                    ]),
            );

        await interaction.reply({ content: 'Pong!', components: [row] });
    }    
});
```

[image: Вот как выглядит 1 меню]

[image: Вот как выглядит при нажатии на oneball]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы когда нажимаешь на oneball select menu удалялось и он отправлял новую, связанную с выбранным аргументом select menu, на фото пример, когда нажимаешь на oneball у тебя выходит новая с другими агрументами